# CKEditor breaking custom .NET tags by converting single quotes to double quotes

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, syntax, ckeditor

At the client's request, we just upgraded a custom CMS system for a large site from FCKEditor 2.x to CKEditor 3.5.3.

Inside an ItemTemplate I have a custom UserControl tag in which the attributes are populated by DataBinding, like so:

```
<my:Viewer runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <my:CustomTag runat="server"
            ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</my:Viewer>
```

So, the point is that the above works just fine.  However, when the HTML is put into the latest CKEditor, CKEditor changes the ImageUrl attribute to use double-quotes instead of single quotes.  Once it's changed to double quotes, it causes a parsing error on the .aspx page.  Changing: `"ImageUrl" to &quot;ImageUrl&quot;` works, but it's not ideal for our client who is going to have to update every page that exists in a very large CMS system.  So, I'm asking this question hoping someone might know of a way to toggle CKEditor to use single quotes in HTML attributes by default instead of double quotes to reduce the amount of work my client is going to have to do.

I'm only looking for easy configuration-type changes, not patching the editor, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to say that the &quot; solution that I mentioned being too much work is simply the only answer...just to put some closure on this.  Or, if I can find a way, I'll withdraw the question.  Thanks rqmedes for trying...I'd actually forgotten all about this question until I got your response

:)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want 
Taken from here 
http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=20647&sid=f47526ecfb1f2303ad0b923ceed7aafe&start=10

To avoid CKEditor changing special chars:
switching in source view:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.TEXT.on( 'mode', function(ev) {
      if ( ev.editor.mode == 'source' ) {
                        var str=ev.editor.getData();
         str=str.replace(/&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&gt;/g, ">").replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&quot;/g, "\"");
         ev.editor.textarea.setValue(str);
      }
});
```

When save edited document:

```
var html=CKEDITOR.instances.TEXT.getData()
html=html.replace(/&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&gt;/g, ">").replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&quot;/g, "\"");
```

Comment: It's not the HTML entities that are causing the problem.  It's that CKEditor actually changes single-quotes to double-quotes around attributes...I would guess that was done for "consistency" or "best-practice", but changing the .NET attributes to double-quotes when there are server-side double quotes inside the attribute breaks compilation.  However, thanks for being the first to try to answer :)